# What is the constant $C$ in the definition of asymptotic notations?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

For example in the definition of $\Theta$:

> $f(n) = \Theta(g(n)$ if there exist positive constants $c_1, c_2$ and $n_0$ such that
>   $$ 0 \leq c_1 \cdot g(n) \leq f(n) \leq c_2 \cdot g(n) \text{ for all } n \geq n_0. $$

I was scratching my head for two weeks since we took this definition in class. Why do we need this constant anyways? Shouldn't we get rid of all constants because they aren't significant?

Why can't we just say $g(n) \leq f(n) \leq g(n)$?

Comment: The constants are there precisely so you can disregard constant factors. They ensure that, as an example, $f(n)=O(g(n))$ iff $Cf(n)=O(g(n))$.

Comment: It seems that your real difficulty is with formal definitions. I suggest reviewing (or studying) "intro to proofs" or formal logic.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus can you explain more why constants can disregard constant factors?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I don't think my problem with formal definition, maybe I have a problem with them, but my priority is understanding the concept of those constants and the asymptotic notations. I don't understand the concept behind them. I mean, if f(n) = n^2 + 1 and g(n) = n^3, then obviously n^3 is bigger than n^2 as n gets larger. why are we even proving that? it doesn't make any sense. and why are we putting this symbol O here : O(g(n)).

Comment: In mathematics, nothing is obvious. We have to prove *everything*.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea of asymptotic notation is that "constant factors shouldn't matter". This has several different interpretations. Taking as our example big O, the simplest interpretation is:

> For all $C,D>0$ and functions $f,g$: $$ f = O(g) \Longleftrightarrow Cf = O(Dg). $$

This means that big O should be scale-invariant, that is, it should treat the functions $f$ and $Cf$ exactly the same. Stated differently, if $f_1,f_2$ differ by a constant factor, then $f_1,f_2$ should be treated the same.

In practice, the condition "$f_1/f_2=\text{const}$" is too restrictive. Instead, we would like to treat two functions $f_1,f_2$ in the same way as long as $f_1/f_2$ is *bounded*, that is, as long as $C_1 \leq f_1/f_2 \leq C_2$ for some constants $C_1,C_2>0$. That is, we would like that

> For all $C_1,C_2,D_1,D_2$ and functions $f_1,f_2,g_1,g_2$ satisfying
>   $C_1 \leq f_1/f_2 \leq C_2$ and $D_1 \leq g_1/g_2 \leq D_2$:
>   $$
> f_1 = O(g_1) \Longleftrightarrow f_2 = O(g_2).
> $$

You can check that the definition of big O satisfies this invariance property. The constant in the definition of big O ensures that. Indeed, while $2n \leq n$ doesn't hold, $2n = O(n)$ does hold.

The integer constant – $N_0$ – in the definition of big O isn't really necessary. It is there so we can accommodate functions which aren't positive or aren't even defined for small $n$. If your functions aren't pathological in that sense, then you can do away with $N_0$.

For these non-pathological functions (extended to non-integer points), the various asymptotic notations have equivalent definitions in terms of limits:

- $f = O(g)$ if $\limsup_{n\to\infty} f(n)/g(n) < \infty$.
- $f = \Omega(g)$ if $\liminf_{n\to\infty} f(n)/g(n) > 0$.
- $f = \Theta(g)$ if both these conditions hold.
- $f = o(g)$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)/g(n) = 0$.
- $f = \omega(g)$ if $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)/g(n) = \infty$.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort for trying to explain, and you took the time to write all this. But I think I got more confused now.

Comment: I suggest contacting a TA. Stackexchange isn't the best forum for discussions.

Comment: What is s TA stand for?

Comment: Teaching assistant.

Comment: You mean in my college? We don't have one, only the lecture instructor is there, and he's taking the lab too, I don't know if he can help.

Comment: Unfortunately that's a problem we can't help you with.

Comment: You think there're others who could answer or clarify this more, or there's only you here?

Comment: There are other people around, and perhaps they'll chime in. You can also try your luck on the chat.

Comment: The stackoverflow network has a chat feature. I'll let you figure out how to use it.

Comment: Your explanation is too abstract. I'd rather have explanation in words.

Comment: You also mentioned reading a book about proof, will I understand why we add this constant if I read those books? Or you're referring to that book for understand the format of proofs?

Comment: There are many such books. It's an entire genre. One example is [Velleman's How to Prove It](https://www.amazon.com/How-Prove-Structured-Approach-2nd/dp/0521675995), but there are many more. There should also be some online substitutes.

Answer (score 2):

> Why can't we just say $g(n)\leq f(n)\leq g(n)$?

Because the only way that we can have $a\leq b\leq a$ is if $a=b$.

Answer (score 1):

I will strongly rely on the intuition here. Consider two excerpts of codes in C language, that does the same thing.

Excerpt 1:

```
if (a>b) {
    result = x;
} else {
    result = y;
}
```

Excerpt 2:

```
result = a > b ? x : y;
```

Suppose that both excerpts are inside a $n^2$ loop. So, Excerpt 1 runs $4n^2$ instructions, while Excerpt 2 runs $n^2$ instructions. We have a difference of constant $c=4$ between the two cases (even though both excerpts do the same thing).

But the difference between $4n^2$ and $n^2$ is realistic? To answer this, we have to know:

**(1)** both excerpts are translated into different machine instructions? we need to know all the details of the compiler used.

**(2)** what area the specific machine (processor) that we are compiling this?

**(3)** what if we change the language, for example, from C to Java? The algorithm will have the same performance? Again, we need to know the how to answer (1) and (2).

So, if algorithm analysis were to pay attention to all these **technological details**, it would be practically impossible or too tricky to come up with useful conclusions. That's the main reason to use the constant in assymptotic notation. It **hides details like programming languages, compiler, processor,** ... But it still allows to compare  different ideas on designing algorithms.